# securing passwords in code

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords

Even with https enabled, you can write a password to the event log in code-behind.  Any way to keep that password encrypted in code while you're checking it against a data store?

(using Login control)

(couldn't add comment to Andrew's answer, so I'm putting it here)
NTLM uses the username/password of the machine the user is logged into right?  For this, I was thinking using ActiveDirectory on the server as the data store.  It would have a diferrent un/pw than what the user is currently signed in to their machine as.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) class.

> Represents text that should be kept confidential. The text is encrypted for privacy when being used, and deleted from computer memory when no longer needed.

Comment: `SecureString` is cool but doesn't really make sense for ASP.NET.  The plaintext password will be passed to the server as a string and will have to be converted to a `SecureString`.  At this point the OP might as well encrypt the password.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending a plain-text password in a form submission it is always available in the HttpContext object. It can't be removed or encrypted during the life of the page. The capability to store it is available the entire time until the finished page response is pushed out to the client. Even beyond that, the password is available in plaintext in memory and accessible through a hex editor (in RAM).

If you're concerned about password's being available in these fashions, you would be better served by enabling the NTLM authentication through Windows Integrated authentication which is hashed from bang to bullets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the plaintext password being in memory simply encrypt it as soon as possible in your workflow.  Also make sure that you never log the plaintext password to any event logs either.

Comment: This really doesn't fix anything. The plaintext password will still be available at all points of the lifecycle through the context object that passed it in the request to begin with. That can't be changed, and it's universally available until the finished response is pushed out.

Comment: @Joel - True enough but any solution presented here will have the same problem.

Comment: not necessarily. It depends on what his authentication options are. If he is stuck with a SQL store or some other similar DB, then that's correct. If he is able to alter his authentication scheme to allow for the integrated NTLM authentication, it will be hashed through the entire process and at no time will the password be available for viewing or storage.

Comment: @Joel - Again, you make a good point, but I still contend that since the OP is clearly using a custom data store that NTLM isn't really feasible for the OP.  Still, excellent point :)